# Limiting the json fields that need to be deserialized into java object's fields

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a Json as:

```
{ 
   "a1":"a1Value",
   "a2":"a2Value",
   "a3":"a3Value",
   "a4":"a4Value",
   "a5":"a5Value" 
}
```

Java class is:

```
class Response {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;

    //public getters and setters
}
```

Now I only need 3 fields from the Json to be de-serialized into the object's 3 fields, I am using Spring 3.2.2 MVC,for REST support(rest template : getForEntity()) , and getting error during the process,How can I ignore these fields in the json ? Also, is there some way, that at the time of serialization also, I only serialize those properties of object that have non-null values at the time of serialization.

Comment: Create your own `MessageConverter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this annotation on class level to ignore unknown properties:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

or with `ObjectMapper`:

```
objectMapper.configure
      (DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

For only non-null:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

or for Jackson `ObjectMapper`:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: I think the last should be `mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);` but I may be wrong. I generally also use `mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL));`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Yes, you right for ObjectMapper can be also configured to skip unknown properties. I can update my answer to get it more detailed)